# Incomplete PhpStorm AMD support when using RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm experiencing incomplete support for RequireJS when using PhpStorm. Dependencies are acknowledged, but the IDE is unable to resolve the dependency interface, resulting in a ton of *unresolved function or method* warnings for example. Am I doing something wrong, or missing something?

For example:

```js
//Foo.js
define(() => {
    function Foo() {}
    Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
        return true;
    }
    return Foo;
});
```

```js
//Baz.js
define([
    'Foo' // PhpStorm does acknowledge the Foo.js dependency, referring to the appropriate file
], (Foo) => {
    let foo = new Foo();
    console.log(foo.bar()); // But is not aware that Foo.prototype.bar exists, and generates a warning
});
```

I'm hesitant to refactor this code into something like `export default Foo;` (which has better support) just to enable better IDE support, as I feel I might be doing something wrong, or missing some sort of plugin.

Is there anything I can do to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a package.json and don't have **requirejs** specified in the dependencies section, please, install it:

```
npm i --save requirejs
```

That definitely could help.

Comment: It's there. But I believe you make a good point. In some of my other projects, PhpStorm does seem to recognize exported details. In most however, it doesn't. And it's not clear to me what the difference is.

In short, `"requirejs": "^2.3.6"` is what my `package.json` contains now under normal dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

With the exact same setup for a fresh project, the IDE was working as expected. So it turns out the project specific IDE settings (or cache?) caused the problem. Invalidating the cache didn't solve it, but removing the `.idea/` folder (and letting it be recreated) did.

Comment: That's very difficult to say what's the reason for the issue without any additional info. If deleting the project folder helped I can guess that there was some problem with jsLibraryMappings.xml file which is stored inside that folder. If you will have any similar issues in the future feel free to post an issue to the WebStorm or PhpStorm issue tracker.

Comment: Also, note that installing `@types/<package>` type definitions significantly improves code completion quality even if you don't use a TypeScript. I'm now working on the automatic installation of those definitions for JS projects so it would be enabled by default in one of the future releases.